# Using xp_instance_regenumkeys without local registry

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to read sub directory names some path which is different domain. I can read manually add the connection to regedit and read. But I can't this in SQL.

This code run in local...

```
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_instance_regenumkeys
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLSERVER';
```

But I want the following:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_instance_regenumkeys
        'DOMAIN\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
        'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLSERVER';
```

Comment: The query will retrieve keys from the registry of the SQL host you connected to. T-SQL is not the right tool to read registry keys from other machines.

Comment: I see. Thank you for answer...